# Why does NSTextField with usesSingleLineMode set to YES has intrinsic content size of multiline text?

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout, nstextfield, appkit

I want to draw single line textfield with default border.

So I entered some multiline text into it(just for test for future cases) and set the flags

Swift:

```
textfield.usesSingleLineMode = true
textfield.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
```

Objective-C:

```
self.textfield.usesSingleLineMode = YES;
self.textfield.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;
```

But I got in console:

```
(lldb) po self.textfield.intrinsicContentSize
(width = 511.5, height = 174)
```

[image]

I've tested all [lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428978-linebreakmode?language=objc)s, including [NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode/nslinebreakbytruncatingtail?language=objc).
[image]

Here is a field in IB:
[image]

Of course I can:

- Overload **intrinsicContentSize** method
- Filter strings keeping only first line

But it looks like a crutch =( Do you have any ideas how to fix it without crutches? Do you think it is an AppKit bug or my mistake?

**PS** In any case, thanks for attention.

Comment: What is the value of `lineBreakMode`?

Comment: @Willeke, It doesn't depend on line break mode, I've tested all accessible.

Comment: Is the text field created in code or in IB? Is the text field editable? Do you want to display multiple lines in a single line text field?

Comment: @Willeke, The field has been created in IB(I've just added a screenshot into my answer). It's not editable("po self.textfield.editable" printed NO, and behavior is set to None, you can see it on a recently added screenshot). I want to display one line only. I am just confused that it displays single line and has a size of multiline text.

Comment: How did you create a big single line label? The default height is 17.

Comment: I just set multiline text into textField's title attribute in xib.

Comment: Don't paste multi line text in a single line text field.

Comment: You are right, but what for the usesSingleLineMode might be used? And it was added in macOS 10.10+. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428929-usessinglelinemode

Comment: See the discussion on the linked page.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. By default the NSTextField is trying to display as much text possible. I made a sample application, that contains a long line of text in the title of the NSTextField. Set it to "Uses Single Line Mode" and set line break to "Truncate Tail". I put leading, top and trailing layout constraints on the view. Now when i input the text into the text field, it will make the horizontal width of the window very wide. This is Autolayout in action.

[image: Truncated text field in single line mode]

To fix this you need to select the NSTextField, choose the Size inspector and set the Horizontal Content Compression Resistance Priority to a lower number. In the sample application I changed it from 750 to low (250).

[image: Size inspector]

Resize content view to an acceptable size, and you are off to the races.